# How to use a view helper in ActiveAdmin form.has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I was wondering if this even possible.

What I've tried:

```
ActiveAdmin.register SomeModelName do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Details' do
      # some inputs
    end
    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :some_model_relation, new_record: true do |r|
        r.input :field do |model|
          # call some view helper method. this doesn't work. nothing's rendered.
          some_view_helper(model)
          
          # I've tried to render a partial. no luck.
          # render partial: 'some_name', locals: {model: model}

          # tried to render partial via block's form. no luck as well
          # r.template.render partial: 'some_name', locals: {model: model}
        end
      end
    end
  end

  controller do
    helper SomeViewHelper
  end
end
```

It seems like `input`'s block isn't called at all. Then how to do it properly?
My ActiveAdmin version is 1.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, inside the input you are in Formtastic and not ActiveAdmin.  You could look at building a [custom Formtastic input](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs) instead.

Comment: I thought it's possible, because I can use it inside of `f.inputs do`. like..
```
 f.inputs 'Details' do
      some_view_helper(object)
    end
```

Comment: If you dig through [form_builder.rb](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb) you'll see the hacks needed to make it work in inputs and why I gave up on trying to make it work with input.